# Determine which RadioType form was selected in contorller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form that has multiple RadioTypes to represent a category for a Announcement entity.

```
$builder
->add('info', RadioType::class,
            [
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'sr-only'],
                'required' => false
            ])

        ->add('star', RadioType::class,
            [
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'sr-only'],
                'required' => false
            ])
```

I plan on having 8 different RadioTypes for 8 choices. What is the best way to determine which RadioType was selected. My current implementation is to have an `if` statement for each but that seems like a poor solution.

```
if ($form->getData()['info'] == true) {
            //do stuff
        }
        if ($form->getData()['star'] == true) {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Comment: Why does `if` seem like a poor solution? You could use a `switch` statement instead, though they're semantically identical.

Comment: If you have 8 radio inputs and you only want the users to be able to select one at the time, then there's no reason to use JS. That's how radio inputs work by default. It's what they are for. Just give them the same name but different values.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson problem is, their code is generating a bunch of unrelated radio buttons with different names, so they aren't linked up at all.

Comment: @miken32 - Unless they do as you suggested in your answer :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i actually tried the suggested answer, but it made styling a lot harder (see my comment to the answer)

Comment: Note this also applies to your own answer, which should be marked as accepted if it's the solution you went with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/radio.html), you shouldn't typically be using `RadioType` directly. Using the [`ChoiceType` object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) allows you to follow expected HTML standards, meaning you use the same name but a different value for each element. This way the browser will, as has always been the case for radio buttons, automatically restrict the user to a single choice.

```
<?php
$builder->add('yourCategory', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => [
        'Info' => 'info',
        'Star' => 'star',
        'Some other label' => 'other',
    ],
    // attributes for label elements
    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'sr-only'],
    // attributes for input elements
    'choice_attr' => [
        'Info' => ['class' => 'fa fa-info'],
        'Star' => ['class' => 'fa fa-star'],
        'Some other label' => ['class' => 'whatever'],
     ],
    // setting these options results in radio buttons
    // being generated, instead of a select element
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
]);
```

Then in your controller:

```
switch($form->getData()['yourCategory']) {
    case 'info':
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 'star':
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 'other':
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing it this way, the issue with that was it made styling very hard. Essentially I want to hide the labels and have only Font Awesome Icons as the "radio buttons". to my knowledge, its not possible with ChoiceType

Comment: @d1596 - You could just skip the form builder and write the radio buttons manually? If it hinders you more than it helps you, then you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @d1596 the `label_attr` option should still be available to do the same thing as in your original code. Or, as Magnus suggests, just do the inputs manually.

Comment: @miken32 the `label_attr` option would change just the single label for the entire choicetype form, no? I need a unique icon for each choice

Comment: @d1596 I don't know, did you try it? From what I can see in the examples, there is no way to specify a "single label for the entire choicetype form" so it doesn't look like it's related. You can specify attributes for each input, but doesn't seem like you can for each label.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up being able to change each individual choice's label manually

```
{# Manually set the label for each choice in the form, so only an icon is shown #}
        <label for="{{ form.choices.children[0].vars.id}}" class="mt-2">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x type-icon" id="info-type">
                <span class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x circle"></span>
                <span class="info fas fa-info fa-stack-1x"></span>
            </span>
         </label>
```